# Euro symbol not showing (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write an If statement that checks an input (a currency) and then assigns the correct symbol to the dollar amount. My code is below, every currency works except for the euro, which only works if the dollar amount is letters, and not numbers. Am I missing something obvious?

```
If Note_Currency = "" Then
    Note_Denomination = "$" + Note_Denomination
ElseIf Note_Currency = "EUR" Then
    Note_Denomination = "€" + Note_Denomination
ElseIf Note_Currency = "JPY" Then
    Note_Denomination = "¥" + Note_Denomination
ElseIf Note_Currency = "GBP" Then
    Note_Denomination = "£" + Note_Denomination
Else
    Note_Denomination = "$" + Note_Denomination
End If
```

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", if you step through the code, does it skip over that part's `Then` statement? Or does it actually follow through, but the `Note_Denomination` is incorrect when it's done?

Comment: @BruceWayne I apologise for my ignorance, I'm a beginner and largely teaching myself, but what do you mean by 'step through the code'? When I run the entire macro, entering the currency as 'EUR', it returns the correct dollar amount with no symbol.

Comment: You can step through the code by using `F8` in when you're in the VB editor.  Quick check: replace the EUR symbol with like "X" and see if it puts an "X" in front at least. If so, then perhaps it's the symbol itself.  Also, I suggest using `&` to connect the strings, not `+`.

Comment: @BruceWayne Yep, once I changed the symbol to an X it worked (for letters and numbers). Is there a way to fix the symbol, or should I abandon this method entirely?
Thanks for the +/& tip, I'll change that.

Comment: Try `Note_Denomination = Chr(128) & Note_Denomination`

Comment: @BruceWayne I now get "Ä". I checked a few other character codes against the table of what they should be, and they weren't what they were supposed to be. So perhaps this is the problem. I went through the codes, and Chr(219) returns the euro symbol, but still doesn't work in my macro. Additionally, it appears as "€" on the sheet, but " '€ " in the formula bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out - kind of.  I tried your sub in Excel and the same thing happens for me. Using the symbol and `Chr(128)` shows just a blank cell.

What I found worked is that if you know your range that will have these numbers, change the cell's format type to Text (`@`):

`Range("A1:A100").NumberFormat = "@"`

Then, when you run your code, the Euro symbol shows up if you use `Note_Denomination = Chr(128) & Note_Denomination`.

SO, it looks like the reason wasn't the code, but the cell formatting.

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you so much! The only thing I would say (in case someone else looks at this), is that I still had to use `Chr(219)` and the cells were flagged for storing numbers as text (but I just disabled this). Thank you!!

Comment: You don't happen to know any vba to ignore the flag within the macro do you? I was going to run this sheet on multiple computers and I'd rather not disable the flagging every time. Also, when I added this code, after the macro runs, most of the column in selected, even if I select a different cell. It only disappears when I scroll. You don't know why this occurs/how to fix this do you? Thanks again

Comment: @1937827 - What do you mean 'ignore the flag'?  What does the rest of your code look like?  As for the column selecting, I'll need to see the rest of your code to know what's going on.

Comment: Thanks - I figured it out myself

Answer (score 2):

It VBA it's a bad idea to concatenate a string and a number using +. Instead you should use &.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_concatenation_operators.htm